# Asammdf: What are channels, signals and samples

Tags: python, mdf, asammdf

I‘m a student who has to work with MDF files and the Asammdf library.

As I am not advanced, I can‘t seem to wrap my head around what the aforementioned things are. Specifically the difference between a channel and a signal.

And does a MDF Object contain all of the channel / signal / sample objects in a list? Do they implicitly get created when creating a MDF object from a MDF file?

I was given scripts that work on MDF files, however I have issues understanding the fundamentals.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is a good starting point for understanding the MDF format https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/mdf/wiki/